# Why sometimes don't we use an auxiliary verb in question sentences?

Tags: verbs, questions

As I know if would like to ask question I should but auxiliary verb.
So why in the following example we don't used the Who was discovered gravity?
"Who discovered gravity?"
I think it should be
Who was discovered gravity?

Comment: Newton was discovered gravity?

Comment: You don't normally use an auxiliary verb with a wh- word that's replacing the subject of a sentence. This is very basic English grammar, and more suited for English Language Learners stack exchange. For the rule, see e.g. https://basicenglishspeaking.com/wh-questions/